# Converting AI to EPS / JPEG without "Use artboards"

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to read(preview) AI (adobe illustrator) file in my web application. my web app is on Linux machine and mainly uses Python.

I couldn't find any native python code that can preview AI file, so I continued to search for solution and found ghostscript, which gives the option to convert AI to JPG/PNG and I these format I have no problem previewing. 
The issue I have is that I need the preview to include the whole document and not just the artboard, in illustrator it's possible when removing the checkbox from "use artboards" when saving, see screenshot: https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/illustrator/how-to/export-svg/_jcr_content/main-pars/image0/5286-export-svg-fig1.jpg

but when I try to export from ghostscript, I can't make it work... 
from my understanding, it's best to try and first convert to EPS and then from that to JPG/PNG, but I failed doing that as well and the items that are outside the artboard are not showing.

on linux, these are the commands I basically tried , after installing ghostscript:

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=out.eps input.ai`

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -sOutputFile=out.jpeg input.ai`

`gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -sOutputFile=out.png input.ai`

if it's not possible with ghostscript and I need imagemagick instead, I don't mind using it... I tried it for 10 minute and just got bunch of errors so I left it....

AI file for example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UgyLG_-nEUL5FLTtD3Dl281YVYzv0mUy

Jpeg example of the output I want: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tLT2Uj1pp1gKRnJ8BojPZJxMFRn6LJoM

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Adobe Illustrator native files are not technically supported by Ghostscript at all. They **might** work, because they are normally either PostScript or PDF files with custom bits that can be ignored for the purposes of drawing the content. But it's not a guarantee.

Secondly; no, do not multiply convert the files! That's a piece of cargo-cult mythology that's been doing the rounds for ages. There are sometimes reasons for doing so but in general this will simply magnify problems, not solve them. Really, don't do that.

You haven't quoted the errors you are getting and you haven't supplied any files to look at, so it's not really possible to tell what your problem is. I have no clue what an 'artboard' is, and a picture of the Illustrator dialog doesn't help.

Perhaps if you could supply an example file, and maybe a picture of what you expect, it might be possible to figure it out. My **guess** is that your '.ai' file is a PDF file, and that it has a MediaBox (which is what Ghostscript uses by default) and an ArtBox which is what you actually want to use. Or something like that. Hard to say without more information.

### Edit

Well, I'm afraid the answer here is that you can't easily get what you want from that file without using Illustrator.

The file is a PDF file (if you rename input.ai to input.pdf then you can open it with a PDF reader). But Illustrator doesn't use most of the PDF file when it opens it. Instead the PDF file contains a '/PieceInfo' key, which is a key in the Page dictionary. That points to a dictionary which has a /Private key, which (finally!) points to a dictionary with a bunch of Illustrator stuff:

```
52 0 obj
<<
  /AIMetaData 53 0 R
  /AIPrivateData1 54 0 R
  /AIPrivateData10 55 0 R
  /AIPrivateData11 56 0 R
  /AIPrivateData2 57 0 R
  /AIPrivateData3 58 0 R
  /AIPrivateData4 59 0 R
  /AIPrivateData5 60 0 R
  /AIPrivateData6 61 0 R
  /AIPrivateData7 62 0 R
  /AIPrivateData8 63 0 R
  /AIPrivateData9 64 0 R
  /ContainerVersion 11
  /CreatorVersion 23
  /NumBlock 11
  /RoundtripStreamType 1
  /RoundtripVersion 17
>>
endobj
```

That's the actual saved file format of the Illustrator file. You can think of the PDF file as a 'preview' wrapped around the Illustrator native file. Illustrator reads the PDF file to find its own data, then throws the PDF file away and uses the native file format stored within it instead.

The problem is that the PDF part of the file simply doesn't contain the content you want to see. That's stored in the Illustrator native data. Ghostscript just renders what's in the PDF file, it doesn't look at the Illustrator native file.

Looking at the Illustrator private data, some of it is uncompressed, but most is compressed, it doesn't say how it is compressed but applying the FlateDecode filter produces a good old-fashioned Illustrator PostScript file, one that will work with Ghostscript.

But you would have to manually parse the PDF file, extract all the compressed AIPrivateData streams, concatenate them together, apply the FlateDecode filter to decompress them, and only then send the resulting output to Ghostscript with the -dEPSCrop switch set. That will result in the output you want.

But neither Ghostscript nor ImageMagick (which generally uses Ghostscript to render PDF files) will do any of that for you, you would have to do it all yourself.

Comment: I'll be able to supply an example file tomorrow , I didn't supply any error code because gs didn't give any error, only imagemagick but i just tried it for few minutes....  artboard in illustrator is like Canvas in Photoshop. in illustrator you can put elements outside the canvas and when exporting as jpeg they can still be visible

Comment: I've added files to the original post.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, is that something you be willing to do for a fee?

Comment: I'm flattered, but I have to say no, I simply don't have the free time. Its reasonably easy to parse out the necessary bits from the PDF file, then reassemble the compressed file. Applying zlib to deFlate the stream would give you the native Illustrator file which you could then run through Ghostscript. You **could** leverage off the Ghostscript PDF interpreter to do all the work, but its written in PostScript which isn't a common language these days.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates on the topic: I've found this:

- https://gist.github.com/moluapple/2059569

This is AI PGF extractor which should theoretically help to extract the additional data from the PDF. Currently, it seems quite old and written for win32, so I cannot test it at the moment, but it's at least some kind of lead.

Comment: I'm really not sure what it suppose to do, but when I feed it with the AI file , it generates a file that I can't read, even with PGF software.